# Floating div is taking up whole row instead of using only left side space

Tags: javascript, css

Please look at the web page below. From the source code I posted you can see the floating div is actually below the image div however on the page the image div stay below the floating div. But I want the floating div to stay at the side bar and move the image div to just below the main menu.

Basically all I want is a floating div so that when I move the page down the floating div will always stick at the same position. How to make the floating div on the left only take space on the left. I don't want the image div to go under the floating div row. Should I just change the css style?

My css:

```
.fl_left{float:left;}
.clear {
     clear:both;
}

div#sticker {
    display: block;
    padding:20px;
    margin:20px 10px;
    background:#fff;
    width:170px;
    text-align: center;
}
.stick {
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
```

My javascript (I am using jQuery):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#sticker");
    var pos = s.position();                    
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (windowpos >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("stick");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("stick"); 
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

My html:

```
<div class="wrapper row2">
    <div><img src="../images/Homepage_image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
</div>
<div class="fl_left" id="sticker">
  <p class="wechatholder"><img src="../images/wechat.png" alt=""/></p>
  <p>微信号: linaielts</p>
  <p>关注微信客服号获取更多优惠信息</p>
</div>
<div class="wrapper row3">
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Is it not because you have got the jquery setting the sticker to `position:fixed; top:0;` or is this happening before you have scrolled?

Comment: maybe set div#sticker to inline-block instead of block

Comment: also please provide css for `wrapper` and `row2`

Answer (score 0):

Your 'sticker' is floating but it still takes a bit of space (170px width), so if the next div (or other element) is supposed to be 100% wide it will have not enough space to fit next to your sticker.

Reduce the width of next element by 170px and it should fit.

```
.row3 {width: calc(100% - 170px);}
```